# Handle User Input with Raphael

Tags: javascript, dom-events, raphael

I'd like to write a simple game using the Raphael Javascript library, but one question is sticking in my mind.

How does one handle keyboard input?  I've looked through the reference material and haven't found any reference to this.  Can you simply pass it the standard JavaScript keypress methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about [Raphaël—JavaScript Library](http://raphaeljs.com/).

If yes, just check the source of the provided samples.

e.g.

[IChart Sample](http://raphaeljs.com/ichart.html)

And you see they use normal js events (onmousemove,onmouseup,mousedown,mouseup,mouseover,...)

Comment: ok, i had looked over the provided demos/documentation, but hadn't noticed anything about keyboard input

only reason i asked :)

Comment: The mouse events are replicated for Raphael objects but it doesn't seem like keyboard inputs are captured as well. No demos or docs for that either.